# How to programmatically check that SAP Business One client is installed

Tags: sapb1

I'm developing a WinForm application that connect to SAP Business One using the SAP Business One SDK.

Is there a recommended method for check if the SAP Business One client is installed?

Any help greatly appreciated.

James O'Doherty

Answer (score 1):

The SAP Business One client can be detected using the following code.

```
    Public Function isSapBusinesOneClientInstalled() As Boolean

    Try
        'SAP Business One Application
        Dim type As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(New Guid("632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60088"))

        Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)

        Return True

    Catch ex As COMException
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: It should be noted that this checks whether or not the version 8.8 of the client is installed, newer clients use a slightly different CLSID (`632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090`) and i don't know about older clients